# Find documents with MongoDB via Cosmos DB

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am attempting to retrieve all documents from a specified collection from MongoDB via Cosmos DB. I am returning an empty list instead of the documents I've requested.

```
def retrieve_transactions(collection):
    client = MongoClient(environ.get('DB_URI')) # MongoClient is imported from pymongo
    db = client[str(environ.get('DB'))]
    transaction_collection = db[collection].transactions
    transaction_list = list(transaction_collection.find({}))
    client.close()
    return transaction_list
```

The primary URI is being retrieved from the App Services application settings. The function successfully retrieves test data from my IDE as expected. This leads me to believe the issue involves Cosmos DB itself. I'm successfully inserting documents to this database from a separate App Services instance too. The database's Insights tab shows find requests and zero failed requests.

I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not really enough to go on here to say what the issue is. Can you show what the value for DB_URI is as well as the same for your IDE? Please redact the exact account name and key.

Comment: It's not the URI. Cosmos DB is receiving the find request and charging request units. It seems like that collection itself cannot be found so the list is returned empty. 

I do have a dot in the collection name (example.transactions)... might that cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the dots (".") from my collection's name.

```
example.com.transactions -> examplecom
```

Cosmos DB (MongoDB API) must not support this structure.